# Why don't diametrically opposed margins overlap with a table being involved?

Tags: html, css, html-table, margins

I wonder why diametrically opposed margins (a margin-top following a margin-bottom) between two block elements (eg. divs) are merged, while between a block element and a table, those margins add up.

Example:

```
<style>
    .a { margin-bottom: 18px; }
    .b { margin-top: 6px; }
</style>

<div class="a">Foo</div>
<div class="b">Bar</div>

...

<table class="a">...</table>
<div class="b">Bar</div>
```

Please note: if I change the table's display property to "block" it behaves just like any other pair of block elements and their margins are merged.

Why is that?

Comment: In what browsers have you observed this behavior? I'm not familiar with the spec, so for all I know, it could be a rendering error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a part of the **box model** called **collapsing margins** and w3 explains it better than i could

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1):

The merge between block-level elements (Divs, etc) and sum up in a block-level element and inline element. [See this for more info.](http://www.codertools.com/css_help_guide/css_block_elements.aspx)

Comment: Does a table count as close enough to inline?

Comment: Please note: if I change the table's display property to "block" it behaves just like any other pair of block elements and their margins are merged.

Answer (score -1):

It is because tables do not have a default display value of `block` but instead of a display value of `table`. If you set `.a { display: block; }` you will see that the margins are indeed collapsed together (at least in Firefox 3.6).

Comment: I think the OP understands that, and is wondering *why* that is.